# How to list all HTTP Cyphers a client supports

Tags: https, cipher

I have a HTTPS client (a GSM modem) where I need to know the supported ciphers to configure my nginx. But the requests just fail and are not even listed in my nginx log.

Is there a simple way to setup a server that just tells me what ciphers are supported by connecting clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering it is likely linked with OpenSSL, I'd suggest `openssl ciphers -V`.

For a more general answer, this largely depends on whether the software provides such a command but on Linux, OpenSSL is fairly widespread.

Edit: Didn't notice you wanted to do this from the server but in that case, I'd suggest running `openssl s_server` which will give you all the details concerning the SSL/TLS connection being established, including the ciphers announced by the client.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Wireshark to log the traffic, then look at the handshakes to see where they fail. That is where the client will tell you what he speaks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes tom my mind, put online an Apache and enable logging of ciphers. The one compiled from sources enables it by default, in extra/httpd-ssl.conf you see this:

```
CustomLog "/opt/apache-2.2.20-p3/logs/ssl_request_log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
```

Then connecting to your device would show on your log file the ciphers used for your connection.